# ODE and raw moments

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, harmonic-numbers

I've read a [piece in MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTrianglePicking.html) where a distribution function $P(A)$ satisfies the ODE $$A^{3}(1-2A)P^{(4)}(A)+A^{2}P^{(3)}(A)-4A^{2}P''(A)+8AP'(A)-8P(A)-96(2A-1)=0.\label{a}\tag{1}$$

It is then inferred that the raw moments of $P$ are $$\mu_{n}'=\frac{3\cdot2^{3-n}\left[\left(n+2\right)H_{n+1}+1\right]}{(n+1)(n+2)^{3}(n+3)^{2}}\label{b}\tag{2}$$

Where $\mu_n'=\mathbb{E}[X^n]=\int_0^1x^ndP(x)$ are the raw moments and $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ is the harmonic number.

My question is: how is (2) derived from (1)? My guess is this has to do with the Laplace transform but this is my first encounter with this type of ODEs so I don't know how they may be solved.

Comment: Did you try to check the original reference? Maybe you should add, that $P(A)$ is actually the *probability distribution function* and not the measure (which I thought first and was slightly irritated)

Comment: Oh, sorry, let me correct that. I've looked at the reference but the implication above does not appear there.

Comment: Why are the moments computed between 0 and 1? Isn't $$\mu_n = \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty } x^n P'(x) dx$$ or is there some assumption that outside the interval $(0,1)$ the function $P(x)$ is identically the constant $0$ for $x<0$ and $1$ for $1<x$? Also is the equation correct? I'm wondering whether this term $96(2x-1)$ is really there... But who knows, maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: I meant $\mu'_n$...

Comment: The context of the problem is the distribution of areas of certain random triangles. These all have positive area (by construction) which doesn't exceed 1/2 (that being the largest triangle that can be drawn in a square). So the distribution is only supported on $(0,1/2)$.

Comment: I would start by integrating (1) directly and using integration by parts (and the fact that $P$ is compactly supported) to simplify a lot of terms.

Comment: Are you sure about the $-$ sign in front of $96$ in (1)?

Comment: I don't know. That's what they have on the original piece in MathWorld.

Comment: @ Semiclassical: Well, according to my calculations, the equation is solvable and the distribution doesn't look compactly supported. You can see a general formula of the distribution's third derivative.

Comment: Unless the equation is valid for some compact interval. I also thought about integration by parts but I wasn't sure what to do with the extra terms' values at infinity... So finally is the equation defined only on an interval $[0,1]$ and the distribution is 0 outside that interval?

Comment: Ah ok I just noticed that the post features an actual link. Ok so the equation is supported on the interval and the derivation of solution I wrote is correct. So the moments are most likely computed recursively by integration by parts of the integral of the moment and then by multiplying the equation by $x^k$ and integrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, but it seems like it requires a lot of work (at least for me). I can show you how
one can solve the equation and find the probability distribution
$P(x)$ "explicitly" (at least up to possibly repeated integrals of explicit functions). Let me replace the independent variable $A$ by
$x$, i.e. $x=A$.
$$x^3(1-2x)P^{(4)}(x) + x^2P^{(3)}(x) - 4x^2P^{''}(x) + 8xP^{'}(x) - 8P(x) - 96(2x-1) = 0$$
which is the same as
$$(x^3 - 2x^4)P^{(4)}(x) + x^2P^{(3)}(x) - 4x^2P^{''}(x) + 8xP^{'}(x) - 8P(x) = 192x - 96.$$
First, differentiate the equation with
respect to $x$ once and obtain
\begin{align*}
&(x^3-2x^4)P^{(5)}(x) + (3x^2-8x^3)P^{(4)}(x) \\
& + x^2P^{(4)}(x) + 2xP^{(3)}(x) \\
& - 4x^2P^{(3)}(x) - 8xP^{''}(x) \\
& + 8x P^{''}(x) + 8P^{'}(x) \\
& - 8P^{'}(x) = 192.
\end{align*}
and after cancelling out the repeating terms with opposite signs
we obtain the equation
$$(x^3-2x^4)P^{(5)}(x) + (3x^2-8x^3)P^{(4)}(x)
+ x^2P^{(4)}(x) + 2xP^{(3)}(x)- 4x^2P^{(3)}(x) = 192.$$ Grouping
together the terms with the same derivatives turns the equation
into
$$(x^3-2x^4)P^{(5)}(x) + (4x^2-8x^3)P^{(4)}(x)
+ (2x - 4x^2)P^{(3)}(x) = 192$$ which is the same as
$$x^3(1-2x)P^{(5)}(x) + 4x^2(1 - 2x)P^{(4)}(x)
+ 2x(1 - 2x)P^{(3)}(x) = 192.$$ Divide both sides of the equation
by $(1-2x)$ and obtain
$$x^3 P^{(5)}(x) + 4 x^2 P^{(4)}(x)
+ 2 x P^{(3)}(x) = \frac{192}{1-2x}.$$ Let us set $f(x) =
P^{''}(x)$. Then the latter differential equation becomes
$$x^3 f^{'''}(x) + 4 x^2 f^{''}(x)
+ 2 x f^{'}(x) = \frac{192}{1-2x}.$$ Next, perform a change of the
independent variable $x=e^u$ and $u = \log{x}$ for $x>0$ or
$x=-e^u$ and $u = \log{(- x)}$ for $x<0$. We work with the $x>0$
case, the case $x<0$ is analogous.

Set $g(u) = f(e^u)$. Differentiate three times the latter
substitution with respect to $u$ to obtain:
\begin{align*}
g{'}(u) &= f^{'}(e^u) e^u;\\
g{''}(u) &= f^{''}(e^u) e^{2u} + f^{'}(e^u) e^u; \\
g{'''}(u) &= f^{'''}(e^u) e^{3u} +  2 f^{''}(e^u) e^{2u}  +
f^{''}(e^u) e^{2u} + f^{'}(e^u) e^{u};\\
&= f^{'''}(e^u) e^{3u} +  3 f^{''}(e^u) e^{2u}  + f^{'}(e^u)
e^{u}.
\end{align*}
Remembering that $e^u = x$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
g{'}(u) &= x f^{'}(x);\\
g{''}(u) &= x^2 f^{''}(x) + x f^{'}(x); \\
g{'''}(u) &= x ^3 f^{'''}(x) + 3 x^2 f^{''}(x)  + x f^{'}(x).
\end{align*}
Reexpressing the derivatives of $f$ in terms of the derivatives of
$g$, we get
\begin{align*}
x f^{'}(x) &= g'(u);\\
x^2 f^{''}(x) & = g{''}(u) - x f^{'}(x) \\
&=  g{''}(u) - g^{'}(u);\\
x ^3 f^{'''}(x) &= g{'''}(u) - 3 x^2 f^{''}(x) - x f^{'}(x)\\
&= g{'''}(u) - 3 \big(g{''}(u) - g^{'}(u)\big) - g'(u) \\
&= g{'''}(u) - 3 g{''}(u) + 2 g^{'}(u).
\end{align*}
Plug these expression in the latter differential equation for $f$
to obtain the following differential equation for $g$
\begin{align*}
& x^3 f^{'''}(x) + 4 x^2 f^{''}(x) + 2 x f^{'}(x) \\
&= g{'''}(u) - 3 g{''}(u) + 2 g^{'}(u) + 4\big(g{''}(u) - g^{'}(u)
\big)
+ 2 g'(u) \\
&= g{'''}(u) - 3 g{''}(u) + 2 g^{'}(u) + 4 g{''}(u) - 4 g^{'}(u) + 2 g'(u)\\
&= \frac{192}{1-2e^u}
\end{align*}
which reduces to the following simple differential equation
$$g{'''}(u) + g{''}(u) = \frac{192}{1-2e^u}$$
which can be solved explicitly. Simply substitute $h(u) = g''(u)$
and obtain
$$h{'}(u) + h(u) = \frac{192}{1-2e^u}.$$
Its general solution is
\begin{align*}
h(u) = g''(u) & = e^{-u}\left(A + \int{\frac{192 e^u}{1-2e^u} du
}\right)\\
& = e^{-u}\left(A - \frac{192}{2} \int{\frac{ (-2) e^u}{1-2e^u} du }\right) \\
& = e^{-u}\left(A - 96 \log{(2e^u-1)}\right) \\
& = A e^{-u} - 96 \, e^{-u} \log{(2e^u-1)}.
\end{align*}
Integrating once more gives us
\begin{align*}
g'(u) & = B + A \int e^{-u} du - 96 \int e^{-u}
\log{(2e^u-1)} du\\
 & = B - A e^{-u} - 96 \int e^{-u}
\log{(2e^u-1)} du
\end{align*}
We need to solve
$$\int e^{-u}
\log{(2e^u-1)} du.$$
\begin{align*}
\int e^{-u} \log{(2e^u-1)} du &= -\int  \log{(2e^u-1)}
d(e^{-u})\\
&= - e^{-u} \log{(2e^u-1)} + \int e^{-u} d\big( \log{(2e^u-1)}
\big)\\
&= - e^{-u} \log{(2e^u-1)} + \int e^{-u} \frac{2e^u}{2e^u-1}
du\\ &=  - e^{-u} \log{(2e^u-1)} + 2 \int \frac{1}{2e^u-1} du \\
&=  - e^{-u} \log{(2e^u-1)} - 2 u + 2 \log(2e^u-1)\\
&=  - e^{-u} \log{(2e^u-1)}  + 2 \log(2-e^{-u})
\end{align*}
So
$$g'(u)=B-Ae^{-u} + 96 \, e^{-u} \log{(2e^u-1)}  - 192 \,\log(2-e^{-u}) $$
Since $u = \log{x}$ and $xf'(x) = g'(u)$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{1}{x} g'(\log{x}) = \frac{1}{x}\left( B-\frac{A}{x}
+  \frac{96}{x} \log{(2x-1)}  - 192
\,\log\Big(2-\frac{1}{x}\Big)\right)\\
&= \frac{B}{x} -\frac{A}{x^2} + \frac{96}{x^2} \log{(2x-1)} -
\frac{192}{x} \,\log\left(2-\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{align*}
Recall that $f(x) = P''(x)$, which means that $f'(x) = P'''(x)$
\begin{align*}
P^{'''}(x) &= \frac{1}{x}\left( B-\frac{A}{x} + \frac{96}{x}
\log{(2x-1)}  - 192
\,\log\Big(2-\frac{1}{x}\Big)\right)\\
&= \frac{B}{x} -\frac{A}{x^2} + \frac{96}{x^2} \log{(2x-1)} -
\frac{192}{x} \,\log\left(2-\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{align*}
Now, one can integrate repeatedly the formula for $P^{'''}(x)$ three times to obtain a general expression for $P(x)$ depending on five independent constant parameters $A, B, C, D, E, F$ which need to be determined by first plugging the expression for $P(x)$ into the original differential equation, and second by taking into account the requirements that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P^{'}(x) dx = 1$ and $0 \leq P(x) \leq 1$.